# How to load jquery-latitude-longitude-picker-gmaps in Mustache.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, mustache, jquery-gmap3

I have a web application,in which I use Mustache.js templating library. I am loading a list of hospitals using a **HospitalListTemplate** as in the code`$(this.el).html(Mustache.to_html(HospitalListTemplate, { 'data': this.model.toJSON(), 'longitude': lon, 'latitude': lat, 'isEdit': false }));` after this I am calling a **mapLoad()** function `function mapLoad(){
    $(".gllpLatlonPicker").each(function () {
        (new GMapsLatLonPicker()).init($(this));
    });
}` which loads Google map using [jquery-latitude-longitude-picker-gmaps](https://github.com/wimagguc/jquery-latitude-longitude-picker-gmaps)  my issue is the map is not being loaded in the template.Debugging in chrome console gives **$(".gllpLatlonPicker")** as `[]` i.e template is not available for the map to load,so map could not be loaded.Is there any way to load the template fully first and then call the mapLoad() function??

Comment: are you initialize template and map in document.ready() function of jquery?

Comment: No,template and map are not initialized on document.ready.Actually,a HTML skeleton is loaded and my template with map in it has to load on another event in to this skeleton.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Places API to get a list of hospitals, the Places API results object will include lat, lon in the following format:

```
    "geometry" : {
     "location" : {
       "lat" : -33.8669710,
       "lng" : 151.1958750
     }
```

Where "place" is a hospital listing), you can either pass the place.geometry.location object, or call place.geometry.location.lat() and place.geometry.location.lng() to get the lat, lon values.